# How AWS opsworks manages user uploaded content

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

Might be a rookie question but unable to get clear answer on the web, so please help. 
Scenario is: I have two instances of php server (Let's say A and B), one instance of loadbalance and one of mysql. Stack is almost ready but one confusion in my mind is what will happen to the photos uploaded by user.

`Suppose user comes to sever 'A' through load balancer and uploads the image which gets stored on my "webroot" folder on server 'A'. Now after few days user visits the website again and this time hits server 'B'. He won't be able to see his image as it is residing on server 'A'. I want to know how AWS opswork handles this problem?? Will it sync the data automatically or some extra chef receipe needs to be created from my side.`

Please guide me on this. I am in process of applying opswork to my website and this confusion is not letting me proceed. Any links will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same on serverfault and got the answer.

`It will not sync the data. We need to apply mannual approach for the same either through storing the data on Amazon S3 or using NFS as intermediate layer`

Link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/662706/how-aws-opsworks-manages-user-uploaded-content